# how to get multiple data with same user id from a table in nest js? suppose i have a user table .how can I get user id matched data?

Tags: mysql, json, get, nestjs, findall

How do I get multiple data with same user id from a table in nestjs? suppose I have a user table. How can I get user id matched data?

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { usertbl } from './usertbl.entity';


  


@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(usertbl)
    private UsertblRepository: Repository<usertbl>,
  ) {}

  findAll(): Promise<usertbl[]> {
    return this.UsertblRepository.find();
  }

  findOne(User_ID: string): Promise<usertbl> {
    return this.UsertblRepository.findOneBy({ User_ID });
  }

createusertbl(Usertbl: usertbl ): Promise<usertbl> {
    return this.UsertblRepository.save(Usertbl);
}
}
```

Comment: Please make the title shorter and include the context in the question. Also, the code snippet needs fixing as it only formats parts of the code

Comment: Where exactly is the problem located? If you have any questions regarding your usersService, you should also include this code.

Comment: @FabianStrathaus  I can not find any orm function to call all the data with same user id .like user_ID:111
it has got: userTable{ 
user_ID:111,card_ID:123
user_ID:111,card_ID:456
user_ID:111,card_ID:789}
here I have to enter in the table first like using findAll(user table)
now I have a option left searching findone (user_ID)
I will not be able to see all 3 card numbers by this 123,456,789.I will get only one card number by this.But I want to show all 3 card informations using user_ID

Comment: @IObert I want to know about how to enter a table in nest js show multiple table data with same user_ID using typeORM

Comment: You should then at least include your model definition + userservice code.

Comment: export class UsersService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(usertbl)
    private UsertblRepository: Repository<usertbl>,
  ) {}

  findAll(): Promise<usertbl[]> {
    return this.UsertblRepository.find();
  }

  findOne(User_ID: string): Promise<usertbl> {
    return this.UsertblRepository.findOneBy({ User_ID });
  }

createusertbl(Usertbl: usertbl ): Promise<usertbl> {
    return this.UsertblRepository.save(Usertbl);
}
}

Comment: Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([usertbl])],
  providers: [UsersService],
  controllers: [UsersController],
})
export class UsersModule {}

Comment: @FabianStrathaus

Comment: Can you just edit your question and add the provided code in there (formatting is as code)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cosnt usertbl = await this.usersService.find({where: {User_ID: User_ID }})
```

This should work but I would recommend checking the [typeorm documentation](https://typeorm.io/) or this article on [wanago](https://wanago.io/2020/05/11/nestjs-api-controllers-routing-module/).

I would recommend also changing the name of variables try following camel case and for types capitalized.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have multiple matches you should use the findBy method instead of the findOne.

```
const Usertbl = await this.usersService.findBy({ id: 111 });
```

You can find more information [on the type orm documentation](https://typeorm.io/find-options).

Comment: not working i tried findBY

Comment: any possible way to communicate live?

Comment: You should at least provide the error you are getting. „Not working“ is unfortunately not a sufficient answer.